# Which of the Angular, Vue, React frameworks should I use?

Tags: javascript, angular, wordpress, reactjs, vue.js

This may be not a platform to ask such question but than I believe this is the platform which can give me a grate advice so can choose the right one as per the project requirement. Or please suggest me the platform where I can post it.

I am going to start an Open Source project in a month or so and of that start preparing myself. Currently doing brainstorming and trying to find best technologies I should use for it.

### Project brief

This will be a WordPress open source plugin project that will allows users to interact with each other. It will be kind of discussion board or forum. The concept is not at all unique and I am pretty much aware of it. However, it will have quite amount of unique feature (under brainstorming) which will solves many problems in the community.

### Suggestions

Since, it will be a WordPress plugin so of course PHP and MySQL are the main languages. What I need help for is to choosing right JavaScript library or framework.

I want to make the plugin certain kind of `Single Page Website` like plugin so once the user lands on the forum/board home page (like bbpress forum home) from there plugin works as a `Single Page Website`.

I aware that can be done using JavaScript frameworks such as `Angular`, `Vue`, `React` but I know none of them. My skill in `JS` is just like intermediate and can just work around for the project not more than that. So I am open to sharpen my skill by doing more practice before I start and ready to learn new technology or framework which can fits with my upcoming project.

**I need your help and suggestion** to find out the appropriate JS framework that I should learn for the project before learn other.

**Please consider** that I am also planning to implement API so other developers can extend the plugin's feature and functionality. So JS framework should allow them to utilize all plugin API

Comment: [Software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: All of three framework you need Node js first. And you want to work with Php then may be vue is good because easy to learn and Laravel use vue js, you know that laravel is Top framework in php.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra +1 oh yeah, you are absolutely right. I need to learn `Node.js` first. Just  one more thing.. which will be better on WordPress?